# Change popup calendar months language

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying somehow to replace clickDate english Jan, Dec and etc. to other language, but I can't find how, because I only got these scripts bellow. idate is in this format - 20150730 and fdate - 2015/Jul/30. When click that day as you can see in picture, it output 2015/Jul/30. I want to change locale date that it won't be not Jul, But in lt_LT it would be 2015/Bir/30. Im not very good at javascripts so im asking help for you guys.

```
<a href="javascript: void(0);" onClick="clickDay('', '');">
<script language="javascript">
/**
*   @param string Input date in the format YYYYMMDD
 *  @param string Formatted date
 */
    function clickDay(idate, fdate) {
        window.opener.<?php echo $callback;?>(idate,fdate);
        window.close();
    }
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Where does the code of the calendar come from? Have you written it? Is it a library?

Comment: It's from dotproject.

Comment: You should add that to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see three different options here.

**1. Dotproject settings**

Under [default user preferences](http://docs.dotproject.net/index.php?title=Default_User_Preferences) you can change locale. I am guessing that should change the language of the dates, but I am not sure.

**2. Javascript**

Modify the Javascript so that a `fdate` in your language is constructed from the `idate`:

```
var month_names = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", ...];

function clickDay(idate, fdate) {
    var year = idate.substring(0,4);
    var month = month_names[Number(idate.substring(4,6))-1];
    var day = idate.substring(6,8);
    var fdate = year + "/" + month + "/" + day;
    window.opener.<?php echo $callback;?>(idate,fdate);
    window.close();
}
```

Of course you will need to enter the actual short names for the months in your language.

**3. PHP**

Add this somewhere early in the PHP of Dotproject (or modify it if there already is a `setlocale` call):

```
setlocale (LC_TIME, 'lt_LT');
```

[Here](http://php.net/setlocale) is the relevant documentation. Since this requires you to mess around with the source code of Dotproject it might not be the best idea. It could mess other stuff up - consider yourself warned.